# NGINX: config set 120s timeout but still report (110: Connection timed out) after 60s

Tags: nginx

I set `proxy_read_timeout` in location config.

```
location / {
  proxy_connect_timeout 120s;
  proxy_send_timeout 120s;
  proxy_read_timeout 120s;
  include proxy_params;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
}
```

proxy_params is

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

http in The Nginx conf is

```
client_header_timeout 300;
client_body_timeout 300;
keepalive_timeout 300;
```

But when I request，nginx report time out after 60s.

```
upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream
```

I can't understand which configuration is wrong or missing. I try to read the nginx doc but I cannot find the answer.